# save snapshot in variable within a loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing

please need help in this why the data(i) variable in while loop give me an error here I want to take a picture after each 5 second and I need it continuous so I used while(1) ...

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb');
i = 0; 
while(1)
    data(i) = getsnapshot(vid);
    imshow(data(i));
    i=i+1;
    pause(5);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `cell` array to store the frame and use the `sprintf` function to not overwrite the frames acquired.

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb');

i = 1; 
while true
    data{i} = getsnapshot(vid);
    imwrite(data{i}, sprintf('imageName%d.jpg',i))%save in the current folder
    imshow(data{i});
    i=i+1;
    pause(5);
end
```

Comment: how I can create a cell array sir ?

Comment: To create a cell array use [cell](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). In the code I wrote  `data{i} = getsnapshot(vid);` creates a cell array. Usually, you should preallocate the cell array before the loop for speed computation, however in your case you don't know a priori what will be the size of `cell`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `data(0)` is the wrong usage. The numbers of rows and columns are must be greater than zero, and suggest that you can use `struct` to save your pictures/frames of video.

```
vidWidth = 600;    % frame\pic width
vidHeight = 800;   % frame\pic height
vidstruct = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth,3,'uint8'),'colormap',[]);
index = 1;
while(1)
    vidstruct(index).cdata = getsnapshot(vid);
    imshow(vidstruct(index).cdata);
    index = index+1;
    pause(5);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of [`getsnapshot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/getsnapshot.html) is an H-by-W-by-B matrix where `H` is the height, `W` is the width and `B` is the number of color channels. In your case you have specified that you would like an RGB image so your output is going to be `H x W x 3` which obviously can't fit in a single element of `data`.

You should instead use either a cell array

```
data{i} = getsnapshot(vid);
imshow(data{i})
```

Or 4D matrix to store the data

```
data(:,:,:,i) = getsnapshow(vid);
imshow(data(:,:,:,i))
```

**Update**

As noted by @Sardar, you need to make sure you initialize `i` to be `1` rather than `0` since MATLAB uses 1-based indexing.

Comment: Also notice the initialization of `i`

Comment: @SardarUsama Good catch